# React Native how to update items in a object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do we correctly update an item in an object? I am trying to update the item isComplete = true or false basic on results from my `db.response`

If what I have is already correct can you please explain to me what is making it work

currently, I am using this.setState() which I am passing a prop to in my componentDidMount with the following values

```
{
  "dbResponse": {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "6149f01736503d7aa9fb138b",
    "instantMessage": false,
    "isComplete": false
  },
  "operationType": "todo_update"
}
```

```js
// Works 

state = { 
   list: [], // This list is filled from a prop on component did mount
};

case 'todo_update':
    const {list} = this.state;
    //Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
    const objIndex = list.findIndex(
      obj => obj._id === data.dbResponse._id,
    );
    //Update object's isComplete property.
    list[objIndex].isComplete = data.dbResponse.isComplete;
    break;

// Does not work. It removes the last object
  case 'todo_update':
      const listStore = [];
      const {list} = this.state;
      //Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
      const objIndex = list.findIndex(
          obj => obj._id === data.dbResponse._id,
      );
      //Update object's isComplete property.
      list[objIndex].isComplete = data.dbResponse.isComplete;
      listStore.push(list[objIndex]);
      
      setState({list: listStore})
    break;
```

Comment: What is `listStore` for?

Comment: just temporary storing the list because I was getting duplicate list when I did not clear the this.state.list

Comment: Please you vote the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Case 1

```
      case 'todo_update':
          const {list} = this.state;
          //Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
          const objIndex = list.findIndex(
            obj => obj._id === data.dbResponse._id,
          );
          //Update object's isComplete property.
          list[objIndex].isComplete = data.dbResponse.isComplete;
          break;
```

In this case `state.list` does get updated, but it doesn't re-render the `Component`. Because `list[objIndex].isComplete = data.dbResponse.isComplete;` is updating your `state` without using `setState` this is called `Data Mutation`. Which is not a correct way to update the `state`

### Case 2

```
// Does not work. It removes the last object
  case 'todo_update':
      const listStore = [];
      const {list} = this.state;
      //Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
      const objIndex = list.findIndex(
          obj => obj._id === data.dbResponse._id,
      );
      //Update object's isComplete property.
      list[objIndex].isComplete = data.dbResponse.isComplete;
      listStore.push(list[objIndex]);
      
      setState({list: listStore})
    break;
```

In this `listStore.push(list[objIndex]);` is responsible for clearing you previous data. Since you are only pushing a single data `listStore.push(list[objIndex]);`.

### Solution

```
      case 'todo_update':
          // This will avoid DataMutation
          const {list} = { ...this.state };


          //Find index of specific object using findIndex method.
          const objIndex = list.findIndex(
            obj => obj._id === data.dbResponse._id,
          );
          //Update object's isComplete property.
          list[objIndex].isComplete = data.dbResponse.isComplete;


          // This will update your state and re-render
          setState({ list })
          break;
```